# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str (in my code,Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
vvod = input('Input: ')
vvod_a = []
for i in vvod:
    vvod_a.append(i)
print (vvod_a)
for i in vvod_a:
    if i == 'a' or 'b' or 'c':
        vvod_a[i] = 'bg'

print (vvod_a)

Traceback (most recent call last):
['f', 'e', 'f', 's', 'f', 'f', 'a', 'a', 'f', 'a', 'e']
  File "/home/n4/Рабочий Влад/PYTHON/coding", line 8, in <module>
    vvod_a[i] = 'bg'
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Help me please,if i in list 'a' or 'b' or 'c', then i will be 'bg'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you ask for `input()`, producing a string. Then you do `for i in vvod: vvod_a.append(i)` to turn this string into a `list` of 1-character strings (for future reference, you can do this with `vvod_a = list(vvod)`). This produced the `list`: `['f', 'e', 'f', 's', 'f', 'f', 'a', 'a', 'f', 'a', 'e']`. Then you attempt to modify some of these with `if i == 'a' or 'b' or 'c':`, but this is equivalent to `if (i=='a') or ('b') or ('c')`, and since a non-empty string is truthy, you then get a condition that's always true.

Then we get to the actual problem: `vvod_a[i] = 'bg'`. You are iterating over the *actual elements* in the `list`, *not* its indices. `i` is a string, not an integer that could be used for `list` indexing.

I recommend the following minimal changes:

```
vvod = input('Input: ')
vvod_a = []
for i in vvod:
    vvod_a.append(i)

print (vvod_a)
for i in range(len(vvod_a)):
    if vvod_a[i] in 'abc':
        vvod_a[i] = 'bg'

print (vvod_a)
```

If you want to tighten up your code, you could use a dictionary combined with the `get` method in a `list` comprehension:

```
vvod = input('Input: ')
change_map = {'a':'bg', 'b':'bg', 'c':'bg'}
vvod_a = [change_map.get(item, item) for item in vvod]
print(vvod_a)
```

Answer (score 0):

As TigerhawkT3 has pointed out, the two main problems in your code are that in the `for` loop you use the actual elements of the list as index (`vvod_a[i]` in line 8), and that the `if` condition in line 7 fails to compare the expression in the left-hand side of the condition with each of the elements in the right-hand side. As an alternative solution, I would suggest the use of enumerate():

```
vvod = input('Input: ')
vvod_a = []
for i in vvod:
     vvod_a.append(i)
print (vvod_a)
for index, i in enumerate(vvod_a):
    if i == 'a' or i == 'b' or i == 'c':
        print(i)
        vvod_a[index] = 'bg'
        print(vvod_a)

print (vvod_a)
```